# Comparing variances of non-normal distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, paired-comparisons

I have edited my OP to try and better explain my data and my questions.

**Background Info**

I have 34 species, and for each of them I identified "category 1" genes. Their counts are in the vector input$gene below.

As a biologist, the category 1 gene counts vary a **LOT** across these 34 species.  In fact, this 'degree' of variation is shocking. My reaction to this was: something is missing in these category 1 counts, **and** missing to different degrees across these species. I thought the missing data might be from category 2 genes. Therefore, I ran my analysis and obtained the counts for category 2 genes for each of these 34 species, provided as input$unfilt below.

Based on a biological stringency criterion, I filtered the category 2 genes counts in input$unfilt to obtain inputfilt counts (also shown below). So for any of the 34 species, inputfilt counts < inputunfilt counts.

**The obvious**

Intuitively I know that when I compare (category 2 + category 1) counts to 
(category 1 only) counts, the former is larger in absolute values than the 
latter.

**Not so obvious (to me)**

My research questions are different. I am not so much interested in comparing absolute values before Vs after adding on category 2 gene counts, but in the 'degree of numerical variation' and its statistical significance (if there exists such as a thing in this case)

To reiterate my question - When I add on the category 2 counts to category 1 counts, does the "degree of variability" across species increase or decrease? Can this change in variability happen due to just chance? If yes, then what is the error rate when I conclude these variabilities to be same, or higher, or lower? If not, then how sure am I - 99.5% or even 100% certainty?

I want to check this twice - once with with filtered counts added on, and another time with unfiltered counts added on.

I hope this edited post helps clarify my question and the help that I seek from forum members. A similar question was raised at https://www.biostars.org/p/483/, with various suggestions provided. But I am not sure if any of the answers there are correct. Sorry again, for the verbosity.

```
> input$gene
 [1]  654  868  720  691  870  289  238  374  167  115  925  185  353  349  504  550  716 
      300  736 1416  816  249  437  397 1321  290  223  608  825  235  850   46  160  366

> input$filt
 [1] 6 2 2 2 5 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 6 4 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 7 1 0 1 2 3 1 0 0 0

> input$nonfilt 
 [1] 67 42 32 32 48 18 22 26 14 13 31 14 34 65 30 27 28 14 37 36 19 13 23 16 
     62 16 18 27 27 33 40 14 21 16
```

Comment: Please restate your question.  Are these really independent variables?  In the probabilistic sense?  Because if they are, there is nothing to test:  when Gene is independent of Filt, Var(Gene+Filt) = Var(Gene) + Var(Filt), so Var(Gene+Filt) has to have a higher variance than Var(Gene) unless Filt is a constant, which it isn't.

Comment: Sorry about that. Please see completely revised post above.

Comment: You're going to have to narrow down what you mean by "degree of variation" a bit; typically with count data, both variance and coefficient of variation are both functions of the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have a test that works with your specific data.  First, I'll state the assumptions:  I'll assume that Gene and Filt are not so different from bivariate normal that the test I'm going to use (Pearson's test of correlation) isn't completely wrong (I think we're OK, it's fairly robust), all pairs of observations $(gene_1,filt_1), (gene_2,filt_2)$, etc. are independent between pairs, and (I'm not sure why I even have to think about this one) variances are finite for all populations considered.

We want to know if $Var(Gene+Filt)>Var(Gene)$.  From the relationship $Var(Gene+Filt) = Var(Gene)+Var(Filt)+2Cov(Gene,Filt)$ we can see that having a positive covariance (or correlation) between Gene and Filt is enough to guarantee that $Var(Gene+Filt)>Var(Gene)$ (since $Var(Filt)>0$).  So we'll just need to test the correlation of Gene and Filt.  I'll use Pearson's test of correlation, called **cor.test** in R:

```
> gene
 [1]  654  868  720  691  870  289  238  374  167  115  925  185
[13]  353  349  504  550  716  300  736 1416  816  249  437  397
[25] 1321  290  223  608  825  235  850   46  160  366
> filt
 [1] 6 2 2 2 5 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 6 4 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 7 1 0 1 2 3 1
[32] 0 0 0
> nonfilt
 [1] 67 42 32 32 48 18 22 26 14 13 31 14 34 65 30 27 28 14 37 36
[21] 19 13 23 16 62 16 18 27 27 33 40 14 21 16
> cor.test(gene,filt)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  gene and filt
t = 2.0628, df = 32, p-value = 0.04733
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.00499998 0.61007441
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.3425864 

> cor.test(gene,nonfilt)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  gene and nonfilt
t = 4.0442, df = 32, p-value = 0.0003092
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3030129 0.7685901
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.5815845
```

Since in both cases the correlation is significantly larger than zero, we can state that Var(gene+filt)>Var(gene) and, similarly, Var(gene+nonfilt)>Var(gene).

EDIT:  I'll add a randomization test of the correlation just to be safe.

```
> null_dist = rep(NA,10000)
> for(i in 1:10000){
+   null_dist[i] = cor(gene,sample(filt,replace=FALSE))
+ }
> hist(null_dist)
> cor(gene,filt)
[1] 0.3425864
> p_value = mean(null_dist>=0.3425864)  #One sided test, positive corr
> p_value
[1] 0.0303
```

For nonfilt, the p-value is 0.0002.  So no need to assume normality.

Comment: Actually, I want to check whether var(gene + filt1) > var(gene)
and var(gene + unfilt) > var(gene). In my naïve understanding, if I calculate the Standard Deviation (not variance) of gene = 333.8639516 
and compare it to SD (gene+filt) = 334.5450379
 and also to SD (gene+unfilt) = 342.5933392
I get an increase of 0.20% and 2.61% respectively.
These are small increases, especially for SD(gene+filt) Vs SD(gene)
So I was curious if this might happen by chance. 
So I am honestly confused with your reply. Perhaps you could clarify, please?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clean up the answer.

Comment: Short answer:  If gene and filt are positively correlated, then the true variance of gene+filt has to be bigger than the variance of gene.  Thus we need to check to see if gene and filt are significantly positively correlated.  They are.  (BEWARE:  This doesn't work the other way around.  If gene and filt were negatively correlated, var(gene+filt) might still be bigger than var(gene).  Luckily that wasn't an issue with your data).

Comment: THANK YOU! OK I think I understand your logic of why var(gene+filt) > var (gene) because cor.test(gene,filt) > 0. However, is a test for Normality  of the 'gene' and 'filt' numerical distributions, like Shapiro Wilk test necessary / QQ plots, before using Pearson's cor test? Or should we directly consider Spearman's Rho or Kendall's Tau? I suspect even with these other choices, likely R2 > 1. But I want to know if that will be necessary  or overkill or even incorrect. Your thoughts?

Comment: You have plenty of data, so you're OK.  I did a randomization test to double check and it rejected zero (or negative) correlation.

Comment: While there is statistical support for var(gene+filt) > var(gene) and for  var(gene+unfilt) > var(gene), as a biologist I wonder if it would make sense to calculate ratios - var(gene+filt) / var(gene) , and var(gene+unfilt) / var(gene) to see if they deviate greatly from 1 or 2 or 3. To help make a judgement call when statistical signifance in this case, also means biological significance. Would a statistician be opposed to this additional  step of making such a 'judgment call' ?

Comment: You can rephrase the result as var(gene+filt)/var(gene) > 1, since that is equivalent to var(gene+filt) > var(gene).  Essentially it's already proven, but the ratio might be worth computing if it is more interpretable.

Answer (score 4):

Consider what happens to variances when we add variables

$\text{Var}(a+b) = \text{Var}(a)+\text{Var}(b) + 2\, \text{Cov}(a,b)$

So for $\text{Var}(a+b) = \text{Var}(a)$ you need

$\text{Var}(b) + 2 \,\text{Cov}(a,b)=0$

But under independence of $a$ and $b$, the second term is zero, so it implies $\text{Var}(b) =0$, which is impossible unless the variable is (always) constant (which it clearly isn't, for any of the variables). The only other way to make the variances equal would require substantial (and in many cases impossibly large) negative correlation.

Needless to say, this is inconsistent with the assertion that gene and nonfilt are independent.

Now consider the case where Var(gene+filt) is compared to Var(gene+nonfilt). If gene is independent of the rest, this is the same as seeing whether Var(filt) is the same as Var(nonfilt).

But you state that filt is a subset of nonfilt, so the "not-filt" cases of nonfilt - by the same argument as we just gave - would have to be constant, which we can see is untrue by inspection.

i.e. there's no need to test anything, since under the stated assumptions the null hypothesis is in each case *guaranteed to be false*.

So unless you mean something other than variance when you say "variance" (which is certainly possible), a test is pointless.

(Needless to say, I believe all of the answers you point to in your link miss the crucial issue and so the various pieces of advice given are all unsuited to your case.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and clarification and apologies for framing my question without much clarity. Please see completely revised post above. Hope you can understand the context and my questions now.